# How can I detect that watchOS app is terminated?

Tags: objective-c, watchos

I am writing SDK which will be used by watchOS apps. I need to catch the moment when the app is closed like at image. Or even when app cames from not running state to active state. For now I can only catch transition from inactive to active.

I already try this:

```
_applicationWillEnterForegroundObserver = [notificationCenter addObserverForName:@"UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification" object:NULL queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        [self willEnterForeground];
    }];
    _applicationDidBecomeActiveObserver = [notificationCenter addObserverForName: @"UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification" object:NULL queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        [self didBecomeActive];
    }];
    [notificationCenter addObserverForName:@"UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification" object:NULL queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        [self willTerminate];
    }];
    _applicationWillResignActiveObserver = [notificationCenter addObserverForName:@"UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification" object:NULL queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        [self willResignActive];
    }];
```

WillTerminate notification does not work at all. :( How Can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a similar function to "applicationWillTerminate()", i can use on AppleWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776177/is-there-a-similar-function-to-applicationwillterminate-i-can-use-on-applew)

Comment: No, I just want to catch that terminate event as shown at image, it will be great if I can create some kind of notification for that. Thanks @Palle

Comment: At least when I test it with a debugger in the simulator, the app will continue to run even though I removed it from the app switcher. You can check when the app becomes the active app or goes to the background with the `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` methods in your `ExtensionDelegate`.

Comment: Also, I am noticing that you create references to all observers except the one for `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`. If you don't create a reference, it may get deallocated and therefore deactivated.

Comment: I added refernce to UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification but method is still not triggered.